# App freezes until image is downloaded and shown. Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com
When I download my PFFile(contains image) in viewDidAppear my app freezes for a while and then it shows the pic. But that is not right. I want UIActivityIndicatorView to be animated or at least shown. I know that this deals with async or something. But I have no idea how to make that work correctly.

```
PFFile* imageFile = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
if (imageFile) {
self.activity.hidden = NO;
[self.activity startAnimating];
NSURL* imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:imageFile.url];
NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

This downloads the image and shows it.

UPD:

```
PFQuery* query = [PFUser query];
[query valueForKey:@"profilePic"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray* data, NSError*     error)
{
PFFile* imageFile = data[0];
[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData* data,NSError* error){
if (!error) {
self.activity.hidden = NO;
[self.activity startAnimating];
 NSURL* imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:imageFile.url];
 NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
 self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
 }else{
 self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile@2.png"];
 }

 }];

 }];
```

UPD 2:

This solved my problem. Both answers were helpful.

```
PFQuery* query = [PFUser query];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[PFUser currentUser].objectId block:^(PFObject* object, NSError* error){
if(!error){
PFFile* imageFile = object[@"profilePic"];
[imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData* data, NSError* error)      {
if (!error) {
self.activity.hidden = NO;
[self.activity startAnimating];
self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
NSLog(@"Profile pic shown");
}
else{
NSLog(@"Error 2: %@",error);
}
}];

}else{
self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile@2.png"];
NSLog(@"Fail 1 : %@",error);
}
}];
```

Comment: Never do Internet access on the main thread.

Comment: How to do it in other threads ? that was the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are not getting the object in the background. Try using a query to accomplish this. If you need more info I can give you the full query as I have this code inside my app :)

Sample code:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {}];
```

To get an image with data:

```
PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"YOURKEY"];
            [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {}];
```

Comment: PFFile* imageFile = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
    [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData* data,NSError* error){
        if (!error) {
            self.activity.hidden = NO;
            [self.activity startAnimating];
            NSURL* imageFileUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:imageFile.url];
            NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageFileUrl];
            self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        }else{
            self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile@2.png"];
        }

    }]; Don't work

Comment: You need to put the getDataInBackground in the query. Begin a query and then get the data.

Comment: check question. Updated

Comment: Try putting the code in viewDidLoad. It shouldn't go in the viewDidAppear. Um your're writing your query wrong..... Try going to Parse.com to learn more about it

Comment: Crashes too. Not knowing why

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things wrong with your code

1. Your query is not right, I can't understand this part `[query valueForKey:@"profilePic"];` if you want to get user have profile pics then you should do something like this `[query whereKeyExist:@"profilePic"];`, but at the moment query you have will bring down all objects.
2. You are downloading image in main thread which make your app free you should do something like this

> ```
> [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
>     if (!error)
> { 
> self.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
>  }                   
> }];
> ```

3. You must check `data.count` before calling `data[0]`, this could crash your application if data array is `nil` or empty.

**Update:**
Getting profile pic for currentUser will be something like this

```
    PFUser *currentUser = [PFuser currentUser];
    if (!currentUser)
    {
    //need to login
    }
    else
    {
// may be you need to fetch 
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[currentUser fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *obj, NSError *error){

         PFFile* imageFile = [[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"profilePic"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {

        if (!error)
        { 
            weakSelf.profilePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
         }                   
        }]; 
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Actually every USER has it's own profilePic(In my case) and I just want to select currentUser and get it's data. How to do it ?

Comment: well, not knowing what for you wrote that __weak type(self)... Fail to try because my internet connection grew and I load all files immediately. Gonna do something with it and then try

Comment: Its typeof u i am not using editor you must check for syntax

Comment: It is typeof, but it's also unnecessary.  Remove that line and refer to `self` in the block.  The __weak self reference is done to avoid a retain cycle but there's no chain of ownership between self and the block.

Comment: well, I did some magic and I still don't realise how, but it loads files much faster. I hope that is not because of internet connection. Anyway gonna test with poor network and write about result